# `/bin/bash ./hoge.sh > out1.txt 2>&1`では、`bash -x`の結果がファイルに出力されませんでした。なぜでしょうか？

Tags: linux, bash

## 環境

- Xubuntu 18.04 LTS
- bash 4.4.20

## やりたいこと

シェルスクリプトの標準出力/標準エラー出力をファイルに出力したいです。

hoge.sh

```
#!/bin/bash -ex

echo "hello"
```

## 起きたこと

shellscriptを直接実行したときと、bashコマンドで実行したときで、出力されたファイルの中身が異なっていました。
具体的には、`bash -x`で表示される実行コマンドが、ファイルに出力されていませんでした。

#### 実行したコマンド

```
$ ./hoge.sh > out1.txt 2>&1

$ /bin/bash ./hoge.sh > out2.txt 2>&1
```

#### ファイルの中身

out1.txt

```
+ echo hello
hello
```

out2.txt

```
hello
```

## 質問

`bash hoge.sh`だと、`bash -x`の結果がファイルに出力されないのは、なぜでしょうか？
また、どうすれば`bash hoge.sh`でも出力できるようになるでしょうか？

※`bash`コマンドを使う必要性はありませんが、興味として知っておきたいです。

Comment: /bin/bash ./hoge.shだとシェバンが単なるコメントと解釈されているためではないかと思います。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

シェバンを解釈するのは`execve`のようです。

[シバン (Unix)出典: フリー百科事典『ウィキペディア（Wikipedia）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%90%E3%83%B3_(Unix))の補足を参照のこと

`/bin/bash ./hoge.sh`ではexecveを呼び出されず、-xが効いていません。

straceで調べてみましたがやはり、`execve`で`hoge.sh`になり替わっていませんでした。

`/bin/bash ./hoge.sh`は`hoge.sh`を単なるデータとして読み込んでいるようです。

---

hoge.sh

```
#!/bin/ls -l
echo hello
```

をbashに渡すと、`hello`と出力されますが、`./hoge.sh`だと`ls -l`が実行されます。